# jQuery UI Sortable Widget dynamically added lists not triggering events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

What I have is have a two sortable list, where one is populated with a set of items. Users should be able to sort between these lists.
They should also be able to create new lists which they can also add the inital items. So the sortable elements are static but the sortable lists are dynamic.

The sortable events are triggered for the initial two lists and work fine. However the problem is with the dynamically added lists. They get added no problem and you can sort items into them. The problem is that the none of the events are triggered such as 'receive' or 'activate', so when I drag an element to one of the new lists I want to get the id of the list, but it never triggers any of those events.

Here is a simple fiddle of it
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt8kzwdz/6/)

```
   $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
 connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
 receive: function(event, ui) {
   var receivingID = ui.item.parent('ul').attr('id');
   console.log('receiving id :' + receivingID);
 }}).disableSelection();
```

This never seems to run on the dynamically added lists

```
function makeSortable(id) {
 console.log(id);
 $("#" + id).sortable({
   connectWith: ".connectedSortable"     
 ,
 activate: function(event, ui) {
   console.log("activated list" + id);
 }}
 ).disableSelection();   }
```

This is what is run when the user adds another list.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/pt8kzwdz/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an update to your JS Fiddle with the problem resolved. [LINK!](https://jsfiddle.net/7csykd4f/)

The `$(".connectedSortable").sortable(...)` chunk needs to be run at the end of the `$('#add_new_list').click(...)` function. The `.sortable(...)` code adds sortable to all existing items but not future items.

The changes I've made wrap the `.sortable(...)` in a function called `refreshHooks()` which is run on page load and again every time "Add New List" is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   function makeSortable(id) {
      console.log(id);
      $("#" + id).sortable({
         connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
         activate: function (event, ui) {
            console.log("activated list" + id);
         }}
      ).disableSelection();
   }    

   var list_counter = 2;

   $('#add_new_list').click(function () {
      $('#add_new_list').before($(
            '<ul id="list' + list_counter + '"' +
            ' class="connectedSortable"></ul>'
            ));

      var lists = {};
      lists.list_id = ['list' + list_counter];
      makeSortable(lists.list_id);
      list_counter++;

      refreshHooks();
   });

   function refreshHooks() {
      $(".connectedSortable").sortable({
         connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
         receive: function (event, ui) {
            var receivingID = ui.item.parent('ul').attr('id');
            console.log(receivingID);
         },
         activate: function (event, ui) {
            console.log("activated list");
         }
      }).disableSelection();
   }
   refreshHooks();
});
```